# How to create C++ API that can accept both Unix and Windows headers?

Tags: c++, unix, serial-port

I'm building an API for serial port hardware, and I want this API to work on both Unix and Windows systems. In Windows I have used **<window.h>** and in Unix I have used **<unistd.h>, <termios.h> and <fcnt1.h>**

Is there away to make the person who uses my API to decide which OS he's using and then use the API? or should I build a library for each system?

I want the person who uses my API to include either unix or windows in the headers for example and then that will decide his hardware. is that possible?

Comment: Yes that's possible, but way too broad to be answered concisely here. Some keypoint's to look up are _Interfaces_, _Pimpl idiom_, _Preprocessor Conditionals_ and many more stuff.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ my API is abstract, it will work on both environments without any issues, so it's cross-platform, however, it's only the serial port class that I have. I have serial port classes, one for unix and one for windows, but only one API class.

Comment: If you already have something, better post an example of your design, and where you're stuck specifically. Note, this isn't something very special, many cross platform frameworks work like this. Maybe study some like e.g. Qt or boost.

Comment: For example, there is such a library. [Qt Serial Port](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-index.html), [C++ cross-platform RS232 serial communication library](https://lucidar.me/en/serialib/cross-plateform-rs232-serial-library/), [Serial Ports](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html), [wjwwood/serial](https://github.com/wjwwood/serial), [libserialport](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd start with a single header that defines the user's interface to the common functionality. This is undoubtedly somewhat different from what you've designed, but something on this general order:

```cpp
class SerialPort { 
    class Configuration {
         int bps;
         enum FlowControl { NONE, SOFTWARE, HARDWARE };
         // ...
    };

public:
    void open(std:string const &name);
    bool configure(Configuration const &config);
    bool read(char *buffer, size_t size);
    bool write(char const *buffer, size_t size);
    void close();
};
```

Then you'd typically have a directory for each OS you're doing to support containing code that implements the `Configuration` and `SerialPort` classes for that OS.

Then at build time you'd decide what OS you're targeting, and build the implementation of your interface for that OS. In some cases, you'd do that more or less explicitly, such as by passing something like `OS=UNIX` or `OS=WINDOWS` when you build. In other cases (especially if you use some cross-system build generator like CMake) the build generator itself would detect the target OS, and let you simply query that in your build script.

Comment: How do you think I should make the programmer use the config class? I did this : SerialPort::Configuration config;
 config.bps = 23; but I don't know how to make use the enum in the class

Comment: @JohnSall: Right now, the enum I've shown only defines the type/names, not a variable to hold them, so the clear starting point is to actually define the variable.

Comment: you mean like this : enum FlowControl {NONE, SOFTWARE, HARDWARE} flowControl; config.flowControl = config.NONE;  is this the right way?